# Better code replacement in nested for loop using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am want to avoid this nested for loop and replace it with any better technique in java8. I read about streams in java8 but in this particular code how can I use java8 streams or anything else to make the code better and mainly avoid the nested loop?

```
List<Country> countryList=new ArrayList<Country>();
List<CountryDTO> countryDtoList=new ArrayList<CountryDTO>();
List<CityDTO> cityDtoList=new ArrayList<CityDTO>();
countryList.forEach(country->{
  CountryDTO countryDto=new CountryDTO();
  countryDto.setCountryId(country.getCountryId());
  countryDto.setCountryName(country.getCountryName());
  countryDto.setCapital(country.getCapital());
  List<City> cityList=new ArrayList<City>();
  cityList=cityRepository.getCitiesForCountry(country.getCountryId());
  cityList.forEach(city->{
    CityDTO cityDto=new CityDTO();
    cityDto.setCityId(city.getCityId());
    cityDto.setCityName(city.getCityName());
    cityDtoList.add(cityDto);
  });
  countryDto.setCities(cityDtoList);
});
```

Comment: Do not use `forEach`... Go through this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/

Comment: I'd replace `forEach` by enhanced `for` loops. There's nothing wrong with nested `for` loops.

Comment: I would consider using constructors. This will make the code much cleaner, and allow you to use mapping easier.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Ok i will remove the for loop but I dont want to use nested for loop as i heard it is not a good practice. Thanks for the valuable reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply general refactoring techniques and extract the logic in appropriate methods. And it is generally better to use a stream and a series of map calls instead of the `forEach` method.

```
List<Country> countryList = ...;
List<CountryDTO> countryDtoList = countryList.stream()
                                             .map(MyClass::countryToDTO)
                                             .collect(toList());

private static CountryDTO countryToDTO(Country country) {
  CountryDTO countryDto=new CountryDTO();
  countryDto.setCountryId(country.getCountryId());
  countryDto.setCountryName(country.getCountryName());
  countryDto.setCapital(country.getCapital());
  List<CityDTO> cityDtoList = cityRepository.getCitiesForCountry(country.getCountryId())
                                            .stream()
                                            .map(MyClass:cityToDTO)
                                            .collect(toList());
  countryDto.setCities(cityDtoList);
  return countryDTO;
}

private static CityDTO cityToDTO(City city) {
  CityDTO cityDto=new CityDTO();
  cityDto.setCityId(city.getCityId());
  cityDto.setCityName(city.getCityName());
  return cityDTO;
}
```

Comment: While trying out the code
     

List<CityDTO> cityDtoList =  cityRepository.getCitiesForCountry(country.getCountryId())
                                            .stream()
                                            .map(MyClass:cityToDTO)
                                            .collect(toList());

 I am getting an error marking on my IDE saying The type CityDTO does not define CityDTO(City) that is applicable here. I can't guess why such a n error is coming up.

Comment: Are you calling `CityDTO::new` by any chance? Have you defined such a constructor? If you use the code I've posted, you need to replace MyClass by the class where the `cityToDTO` static method is located.

Comment: Thanks @assylias its fine now...error is no more there.

Answer (score 3):

I would add a conversion constructor or factory to CountryDTO

```
List<Country> countryList = ... some data
List<CountryDTO> dtoList = countryList.stream()
                                      .map(CountryDTO::new)
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You would need to add a constructor to CountryDTO

```
public CountryDTO(Country country) {
```

alternatively you could use a factory method

```
public static CountryDTO from(Country country) {
```